# How to turn left navigation tree to old style in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I don't like new AJAXed style of navigation tree in phpMyAdmin and I would like to change it to the old one. Is there some config directive I can change?

[image: phpmyadmin navigation tree new to old]

- Old version: 3.3.7
- New version: 4.0.4
- Original theme in both of them.

Comment: I'm with you Martin. I wish there was a way to go back to the old style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration directive to change to the old (pre-4.0) style.

However there have been improvements regarding the navigation panel in 4.0.x (current stable is 4.0.9) and in the newly released 4.1.0-rc1.

Updated:
With the version 4.4 of phpMyAdmin (soon to be released I think), it will be possible to revert back to old-style navigation panel with a database selector and only current databases' tables being displayed.
For switching this behavior, set configuration option $cfg['ShowDatabasesNavigationAsTree'] to 'false'.